# Unable to clear data from sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

This is the code of my sharedpreferences.It is working well in putting and retriving data but not able to clear data from sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("userDataInSharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sharedPreferences1.edit();
                    editor.putString("loginas", loginas_);
                    editor.putString("name", name_);
                    editor.putString("yearofbirth", yearofbirth_);
                    editor.putString("gender", gender_);
                    editor.apply();


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userDataInSharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String uname = sharedPreferences1.getString("name", "");
        String udob = sharedPreferences1.getString("yearofbirth", "");
        String ugender = sharedPreferences1.getString("gender", "");
        String uspeci = sharedPreferences1.getString("loginas", "");
        UserName.setText(uname);
        Birth_date.setText(udob);
        Usergender.setText(ugender);
        Specification.setText(uspeci);


        binding.logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences1.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();

//                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("autoLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey Arya. Can you please tell us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: by mistake I put tag.....

Comment: How are you observing that the data is not cleared?

Comment: after clicking on logout it showing me the same thing when i reopen the app

Answer (score 1):

to clear one string :

```
sharedPreferences.edit().remove("name").commit();
```

to clear all strings :

```
sharedPreferences.edit().clear().apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using any singleton class where you might be retrieving the values of these variables using SharedPreferences. The instance of this class need to be set to null too along with above solution.

Comment: The same thing occurred while using the MVVM architecture where I was retrieving data through SharedPreferences in my Repository Singleton class. Even after clicking log out, the old login credentials were seen in some fragments . I observed that only on clearing app, old data was getting destroyed. It all happened due to the fact that this Singleton class instance was still alive and holding the old values.

Answer (score 0):

To clear it you need to add this code

```
public void clear(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
}
```